# Celect2 как в options сделать часть текста жирным?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Поставил celect2, пытался как-то задействовать в option, теги b, strong но так нельзя, их просто не видно, какие теги можно использовать внутри option?

Хотел реализовать так, выделить цену

```html
<select name="cel" id="cel" class="js-select2">
  <option value="Вариант 1">Вариант 1 - <b>500</b> руб</option>
  <option value="Вариант 2">Вариант 2 - <b>1000</b> руб</option>
</select>
```

Еще пробовал для селекта скрипт, который из атрибута берет цену и вставляет в конце текста и можно сделать жирным.

```js
$('#cel').select2({
  formatResult: function(object) {
    var $el = $(object.element),
      name = $el.text(),
      price = $el.attr('data-price');
    return '<b>' + name + '</b>' + '<b>' + price + '</b>';
  }
});
```

и селект для этого скрипта

```html
<select name="cel" id="cel" class="js-select2">
  <option value="Вариант 1" data-price="500">Вариант 1</option>
  <option value="Вариант 2" data-price="1000">Вариант 2</option>
</select>
```

Вообщем то к чему я щас пришел, все работает, но почему то жирным не делает, а просто тег  выводит с результатом.

И как еще данную функцию сделать чтобы срабатывала не для всех селектов, а допустим для id="cel1", я про function formatState(object)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.js-select2').select2({
    minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
    language: "ru",
    templateResult: formatState, //показывает цену когда выбрал в результате
    templateSelection: formatState, //показывает цену при выборе в option
  });

  //функция для подгрузки цены из data-price в option
  function formatState(object) {
    var $el = $(object.element),
      name = $el.text(),
      price = $el.attr('data-price');

    return '' + name + '' + ' - <b>' + price + '</b> руб';
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unique-store.vl-it.ru/media/celect2/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unique-store.vl-it.ru/media/celect2/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<select name="cel" id="cel" class="js-select2">
  <option value="Вариант 1" data-price="500">Вариант 1</option>
  <option value="Вариант 2" data-price="1000">Вариант 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение.
Надо было добавить escapeMarkup: function(markup) { return markup; },

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-select2').select2({
      minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
      escapeMarkup: function(markup) { return markup; },
      language: "ru",
      templateResult: formatState,
      templateSelection: formatState,
    });

function formatState(object) {
      var $el = $(object.element),
        name = $el.text(),
        price = $el.attr('data-price');
    
      return '' + name + '' + ' - <b>' + price + '</b> руб';
    };
```

Добавляю еще вариант решения, можно вот так. (Без escapeMarkup: function(markup) { return markup; },)

```
   function formatState(object) {
      var $el = $(object.element),
        name = $el.text(),
        price = $el.attr('data-price');

      return $('<span>' + name + ' - <strong>' + price + '</strong> руб</span>');
    };
```

---

И если кому надо доработка, если в друг нет цены и выводиться (руб) ну или еще чего, то тут с проверкой, чтоб не выводить доп это слово.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-select2').select2({
      minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
      escapeMarkup: function(markup) { return markup; },
      language: "ru",
      templateResult: formatState,
      templateSelection: formatState,
    });
    
    //функция для подгрузки цены из data-price в option
    function formatState(object) {
      var $el = $(object.element),
        name = $el.text(),
        price = $el.attr('data-price');
        if (price) {
            price = ' - <b>' + price + '</b> руб';
        } else {
            price = '';
        }

      return '' + name + '' + price;
    };
  });
```

А если кому надо сделать чтоб для определенного селекта срабатывало, то вот вариант, бывает не один селект на странице. Допустим хотим применить к селекту2 под id cel100

```
 $('#cel100.js-select2').select2({
      minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
      escapeMarkup: function(markup) { return markup; },
      language: "ru",
      templateResult: formatStateBold,
      templateSelection: formatStateBold,
    });
    
    function formatStateBold(object) {
      var $el = $(object.element),
        name = $el.text(),
        price = $el.attr('data-price');
        if (price) {
            price = ' - <b>' + price + '</b> руб';
        } else {
            price = '';
        }

      return '' + name + '' + price;
    };
```